# Pattern for Matching for Numeric 3 Vector

Tags: argument-patterns

I'm trying to write a basic molecular dynamics sim in Mathematica and would like to define a function calculateForces that takes two arguments. The first is a 3 vector for the coordinates of a particle and I would like to have a pattern that only accepts a 3d numeric vector. This seems like a pretty basic thing but I can't find an answer. Here's the basic definition I have:

```
calculateForces[inputParticle:{_,_,_}]:=
```

This correctly gives me a function that only accepts a list with 3 items. Now I'd like to restrict each blank to a numerical value. I've tried:

```
calculateForces[inputParticle:{_?NumericQ,_?NumericQ,_?NumericQ}]:=
```

and

```
calculateForces[inputParticle:{x_,y_,z_}/;NumericQ[x]&&NumericQ[y]&&NumericQ[z]]:=
```

But both accept nonnumerical values. What would be a good way to solve this? Even if my solutions did work, they seem kinda messy so I would like to know how a much more knowledgeable programmer would tackle this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you want explicit numbers, use NumberQ.

Comment: You probably just need to do `Clear[calculateForces]` and then redefine your input.

Comment: Oh, good call @CarlWoll. I didn't understand that this might be a problem with overloaded definitions. So, StealthyLlama, if you look at Information[calculateForces], you'll see if you have multiple definitions. They will be listed in order of how constrained/specific they are. So, if you have a lingering one with { _ , _ , _ }, that'll be the catchall that'll be used for non-numeric inputs. Use Clear and then re-evaluate just the definition you want.

Comment: Yep you guys are exactly right. It was using the old definition. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`PatternSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternSequence) to avoid the repeated [`NumericQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericQ) pattern tests:

```
Clear[calculateForces]
calculateForces[inputParticle:{PatternSequence[_,_,_]?NumericQ}] := f[inputParticle]
```

For example:

```
calculateForces[{1, 2, π}]
```

> f[{1, 2, π}]}]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`VectorQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorQ.html) to look for a numerical vector, and constrain it to a desired length:

```
threevectorQ = VectorQ[#, NumericQ] && Length[#] == 3 &;

Clear[calculateForces]
calculateForces[inputParticle_?threevectorQ] := f[inputParticle]

calculateForces[{9, GoldenRatio, I}]
(*    f[{9, GoldenRatio, I}]    *)
```